# Highcharts maps with decimals

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, csv, highcharts

I try to replicate [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/42fk8raL/) example file of highcharts with a different kind of data file. In the new database, life expectancy per country is 13 decimal places. The source is also world bank, which makes the structure comparable. Here is the example [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/nf66rzab/5/). Unfortunately, this does not work because presumably "numRegex = /^[0-9.]+$/" on line 26 is wrong. Unfortunately I have no idea what should be put here.

HTML

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.css">

<!-- Flag sprites service provided by Martijn Lafeber, https://github.com/lafeber/world-flags-sprite/blob/master/LICENSE -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//github.com/downloads/lafeber/world-flags-sprite/flags32.css" />

<div class="container_fluid">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
  <div class="panel color-orange shadow">
    <div class="panel-heading  text-white text-center">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body color-grey text-center">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 position-padding-ver position-padding-hor">
        <div id="wrapper_landkaart">
          <div id="container"></div>
          <div id="info">
            <span class="f32"><span id="flag"></span></span>
            <h2></h2>
            <div class="subheader">Click countries to view history</div>
            <div id="country-chart"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
      $.ajax({
    url: 'https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/WZkkd6c4S3euwmgoV88v',
    success: function(csv) {

      // Parse the CSV Data
      /*Highcharts.data({
          csv: data,
          switchRowsAndColumns: true,
          parsed: function () {
              console.log(this.columns);
          }
      });*/

      // Very simple and case-specific CSV string splitting
      function CSVtoArray(text) {
        return text.replace(/^"/, '')
          .replace(/",$/, '')
          .split('","');
      }

      csv = csv.split(/\n/);

      var countries = {},
        mapChart,
        countryChart,
        numRegex = /^[0-9\.]+$/,
        lastCommaRegex = /,\s$/,
        quoteRegex = /\"/g,
        categories = CSVtoArray(csv[2]).slice(4);

      // Parse the CSV into arrays, one array each country
      $.each(csv.slice(3), function(j, line) {
        var row = CSVtoArray(line),
          data = row.slice(4);

        $.each(data, function(i, val) {
          val = val.replace(quoteRegex, '');
          if (numRegex.test(val)) {
            val = parseInt(val, 10);
          } else if (!val || lastCommaRegex.test(val)) {
            val = null;
          }
          data[i] = val;
        });

        countries[row[1]] = {
          name: row[0],
          code3: row[1],
          data: data
        };
      });

      // For each country, use the latest value for current population
      var data = [];
      for (var code3 in countries) {
        if (countries.hasOwnProperty(code3)) {
          var value = null,
            year,
            itemData = countries[code3].data,
            i = itemData.length;

          while (i--) {
            if (typeof itemData[i] === 'number') {
              value = itemData[i];
              year = categories[i];
              break;
            }
          }
          data.push({
            name: countries[code3].name,
            code3: code3,
            value: value,
            year: year
          });
        }
      }

      // Add lower case codes to the data set for inclusion in the tooltip.pointFormat
      var mapData = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['custom/world']);
      $.each(mapData, function() {
        this.id = this.properties['hc-key']; // for Chart.get()
        this.flag = this.id.replace('UK', 'GB').toLowerCase();
      });

      // Wrap point.select to get to the total selected points
      Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Point.prototype, 'select', function(proceed) {

        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

        var points = mapChart.getSelectedPoints();
        if (points.length) {
          if (points.length === 1) {
            $('#info #flag').attr('class', 'flag ' + points[0].flag);
            $('#info h2').html(points[0].name);
          } else {
            $('#info #flag').attr('class', 'flag');
            $('#info h2').html('Comparing countries');

          }
          $('#info .subheader').html('<h4>Historical population</h4><small><em>Shift + Click on map to compare countries</em></small>');

          if (!countryChart) {
            countryChart = Highcharts.chart('country-chart', {
              chart: {
                height: 250,
                spacingLeft: 0
              },
              credits: {
                enabled: false
              },
              title: {
                text: null
              },
              subtitle: {
                text: null
              },
              xAxis: {
                tickPixelInterval: 50,
                crosshair: true
              },
              yAxis: {
                title: null,
                opposite: true
              },
              tooltip: {
                split: true
              },
              plotOptions: {
                area: {
                  color: '#fa7921'
                },
                series: {
                  animation: {
                    duration: 500
                  },
                  marker: {
                    enabled: false
                  },
                  threshold: 0,
                  pointStart: parseInt(categories[0], 10)
                }
              }
            });
          }

          $.each(points, function(i) {
            // Update
            if (countryChart.series[i]) {
              /*$.each(countries[this.code3].data, function (pointI, value) {
                  countryChart.series[i].points[pointI].update(value, false);
              });*/
              countryChart.series[i].update({
                name: this.name,
                data: countries[this.code3].data,
                type: points.length > 1 ? 'line' : 'area'
              }, false);
            } else {
              countryChart.addSeries({
                name: this.name,
                data: countries[this.code3].data,
                type: points.length > 1 ? 'line' : 'area'
              }, false);
            }
          });
          while (countryChart.series.length > points.length) {
            countryChart.series[countryChart.series.length - 1].remove(false);
          }
          countryChart.redraw();

        } else {
          $('#info #flag').attr('class', '');
          $('#info h2').html('');
          $('#info .subheader').html('');
          if (countryChart) {
            countryChart = countryChart.destroy();
          }
        }
      });

      // Initiate the map chart
      mapChart = Highcharts.mapChart('container', {

        title: {
          text: 'Population history by country'
        },

        subtitle: {
          text: 'Source: <a href="http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.POP.TOTL/countries/1W?display=default">The World Bank</a>'
        },

        mapNavigation: {
          enabled: true,
          buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
          }
        },

        colorAxis: {
          type: 'logarithmic',
          endOnTick: false,
          startOnTick: false,
          minColor: '#9E90B3',
          maxColor: '#3D1C5C',
          min: 50000
        },

        tooltip: {
          footerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px">(Click for details)</span>'
        },

        series: [{
          data: data,
          mapData: mapData,
          joinBy: ['iso-a3', 'code3'],
          name: 'Current population',
          allowPointSelect: true,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          states: {
            select: {
              color: '#D06918',
              borderColor: 'black',
              dashStyle: 'shortdot'
            }
          }
        }]
      });

      // Pre-select a country
      mapChart.get('us').select();
    }
  });
```

Hopefully someone can help me further on this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSV file is broken it looks like this:

```
"Data Source,""World Development Indicators"","
```

it should look like

```
"Data Source","World Development Indicators",
```

CSV won't split on a `,` if it's in quotes hence you can include comma's in your file as text if you include them in quotes.

Fix your CSV file and it should work.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! I have modified the database. This makes the map work, but unfortunately the chart (area) does not work yet (see new JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/nf66rzab/20/). Do you have a solution or the reason why it does not work? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hey, your chart was using the inccorect line of the CSV for the dates.

If you look at the CSV line 5 is the line that we see the dates, the code should therefore be `categories = CSVtoArray(csv[4]).slice(4);`

https://jsfiddle.net/nf66rzab/24/